# how can use variable every time from first input

Tags: python, python-3.x

who can help me with the script?

If the audiofile.tag.genre is empty, i would like to enter the genre via input,

and every time when the audiofile.tag.genre is empty I want to accept the first genre from enter input

```
import eyed3
import eyed3.mp3
import sys, os, subprocess
import os, datetime

def get4():
    global genre

    if not genre:   
        while (True):
            try:
                genre = input("Input Genre: ")
            except ValueError:
                break
            break
            return genre
    else:
        return genre

topath = r"c:\dn"

def get(topath):
    os.chdir(topath)
    for filename in os.listdir(topath):
        if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
            audiofile = eyed3.load(filename)
            if not audiofile.tag.genre:
                get4()
                audiofile.tag.genre = genre
                audiofile.tag.save()

get(topath)
```

error:

```
 name 'genre' is not defined
```

Comment: `get` is not defined. As well `sys`, `subprocess`, and `datetime` are unused. You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: edit: def get(topath) its correct

Comment: OK, now `genre` is not defined, because you haven't defined it. What were you expecting to happen? And why do you make it a global *and* return it?

Comment: Why does your `while` loop have an unconditional `break`? And why do you have `return genre` in the loop when you `break` right before it?

Comment: Are you trying to [ask the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4518341)?

Comment: i forgot 2 lines, i need the genre, in def get (topath)

Comment: I've tried so much, I don't know how it should look that it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214022/discussion-between-kuck-and-wjandrea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214022/discussion-between-kuck-and-wjandrea), you want to get user input only if the mp3 doesn't have a genre already, but then use that same input for all the following mp3's. You can do that by setting a default, `genre = None`, then checking `genre is None` when needed.

Also I would use a more descriptive name than `get4`, like `get_genre`.

```
def get(topath):
    genre = None  # Default before user input
    ...
    if not audiofile.tag.genre:
        if genre is None:
            genre = get_genre()
        audiofile.tag.genre = genre
        audiofile.tag.save()
```

This way you don't use a global (which is messy), and you can simplify `get_genre` down to just asking the user for the genre then returning it.